# Selecting possible sum fillers

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I've got to write a program in which the user should input some kind of package weight and distance for sending it with 3 type of post marks with user inputted values and it has to print out every possible combination of post marks on the package. Usually, I've got no problems with combinatoric algorithms, but I don't think this has something to do with combinatorics since the values of the numbers matter. I've been thinking for hours cant figure anything out. This is my source just for the function I'm in.

```
float weight,price,total_price,m1,m2,m3;
int zone;

system("cls");

cout<<"Input package weight: ";
cin>>weight;

    if (weight<0 && weight>10) error();

   else if (weight<1) price=20;
   else if (weight<2) price=35;
   else if (weight<5) price=70;
   else price=120;

system("cls");

cout<<"Input zone(1/2/3): ";
cin>>zone;

    switch(zone)
    {
        case 1: total_price=price*1;    break;
        case 2: total_price=price*1.2;  break;
        case 3: total_price=price*1.5;  break;
        default: error();

system("cls");

cout<<"Input your mark price(1/3): ";
cin>>m1;
system("cls");
cout<<"Input your mark price(2/3): ";
cin>>m2;
system("cls");
cout<<"Input your mark price(3/3): ";
cin>>m3;

output();
```

Comment: What's the question?  Is the output wrong, is it crashing...?

Comment: What does 'output();' do?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have an efficient way to get the desired result ( I am still learning the basics of algorithms :) ), but I believe the following approach will do the trick.

Let’s start simple.
If the requirement was with just two stamps,

- Find the max among the two stamp prices, and divide the total cost by
  this ( taking value as a size_t to remove fractional part ). This
  returns the total number of time the costlier stamp can be used for
  to send the package.
- Now iterate from 0 to this count. The iteration
  index represents the number of costlier stamp used. Find the
  remaining amount for which we have to use the cheaper stamp. If we
  could perfectly divide the remains amount with the cheaper stamp (
  fmod( diff, price_of_cheaper_stamp ) ), we have one of the set that
  we need. That is ( iteration_index, diff/price_of_cheaper_stamp ).
- Continue the iteration to find the remaining sets.

Code would look as follows:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::size_t, std::size_t > >
GetCombinations( double inTotal, double inM1, double inM2 )
{
    std::vector< std::pair< std::size_t, std::size_t > > result;
    auto maxVal = std::max( inM1, inM2 );
    auto minVal = std::min( inM1, inM2 );
    std::size_t maxCount = inTotal / maxVal;
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i <= maxCount; ++i )
    {
        auto diff = inTotal - ( maxVal * i );
        if( fmod(diff, minVal) == 0 )
        {
            result.emplace_back( i, diff / minVal );
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

We can now extend this to have the three stamp scenario.

- We will take the price of the costliest stamp. Find maximum number of
  time we can use that stamp.
- Then iterate from 0 till the count, And for the difference in amount
  that needs to be compensated with the cheaper stamps, compute the
  combinations using the previous approach.

Code would look as follows:

```
struct Set
{
    std::size_t x;  // count of costliest stamp
    std::size_t y;
    std::size_t z;  // count of cheapest stamp
};

std::vector< Set >
GetCombinations( double inTotal, double inM1, double inM2, double inM3 )
{
    std::vector< Set > result;
    auto maxVal = std::max( inM1, std::max( inM2, inM3 ) );
    std::size_t maxCount = inTotal/maxVal;

    // Find the prices of cheaper stamps.
    auto m1 = std::min( inM1, inM2 );
    auto m2 = std::min( inM2, inM3 );
    for( std::size_t i=0; i <= maxCount; ++i )
    {
        auto diff = inTotal - ( maxVal * i );
        auto subCombinations = GetCombinations( diff, m1, m2 );
        for( auto const & subComb : subCombinations )
        {
            result.push_back( Set{ i, 0, 0 } );
            result.back().y = subComb.first;
            result.back().z = subComb.second;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can find the complete code in : https://ideone.com/OkIDKK